# Oauth token requests before provider credentials issuance

Tags: java, rest, oauth, launchpad, signpost

Please forgive me if I ask something stupid, I am a novice here. I need to implement OAuth in my Java application to authenticate against launchpad.net API. The [documentation](https://help.launchpad.net/API/SigningRequests) specifies an initiation of a token request with three parameters : oauth_consumer_key e.g. (name of my application), oauth_signature_method e.g. "PLAINTEXT" and oauth_signature e.g. The string "&". I realised that most OAuth libraries require that 
I have already acquired a Consumer key and Consumer Id/Secret from 
the OAuth provider (e.g as issued in Twitter), and most examples are organised in this manner. However, launchpad.net will issue these parameters only after issuance of request token (they use no third party provider). How can I proceed?I am currently stuck after trying some libraries that threw errors. Many thanks for any useful information. The official launchpad library is in python.

My initial code is below:

```
public class Quicky {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://launchpad.net/+request-token");
            CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
try {
                System.out.println("Your current GET request status:" + response1.getStatusLine());
                HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
  EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
            } finally {
                response1.close();
            }

            HttpRequest request;
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://launchpad.net/+request-token");
            PostMethod poster = new PostMethod();
            List <NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_customer_key", "XXXX"));
            postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_signature_method", "PLAINTEXT"));
            postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_signature", "&"));
   httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams, "utf-8"));
//            httpPost.setEntity(entity1);
            httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpParameters requestParams = (HttpParameters) postParams;
            CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            try {
                System.out.println("Your current POST request status:" + response2.getStatusLine());
                HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
                // do something useful with the response body
                // and ensure it is fully consumed
                EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
            } finally {
                response2.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far and be specific. You have a legitimately good question but it is likely to be shut down because you are not providing enough information.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for your useful observation. I have added my code. I get a 401 when I run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue error messages after some research and code re-factoring. The correct code is below, maybe it could be useful to someone out there.

```
    public class LaunchPadTokenRetriever {  

   public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException,       IOException{

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://launchpad.net/+request-token");
    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    List <NameValuePair> urlParams = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_signature", "&"));
    urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_consumer_key", "tester"));
    urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_signature_method", "PLAINTEXT"));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParams));
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    System.out.println(response);

    try {
      System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
      String responseBody =  httpclient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
      System.out.println("Initial credentials ---> "+ responseBody);
      System.out.println();    
      String getresponse = responseBody;

      EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    } finally {
      response.close();
    }
  }

}
```